# How can I copy the text of the Interactive Playground page in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I thought this page would be very useful for me. So I wanted to save it on my local computer. But I could not copy the text in it.

I tried several ways:

- right-click: invalid
- try to find the file: don't know the name
- search on Google but there is no solution now

Can somebody help me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is called [`vs_code_editor_walkthrough.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/workbench/contrib/welcomeWalkthrough/browser/editor/vs_code_editor_walkthrough.ts) in the GitHub repository for Visual Studio Code.  You stated you were after *the text* of the file, so if you view it in its [raw form](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/vscode/main/src/vs/workbench/contrib/welcomeWalkthrough/browser/editor/vs_code_editor_walkthrough.ts) you can easily get all of the text in its markdown format.

It won't look anywhere near as pretty as Visual Studio Code renders it.  If you want to achieve that look, you'll probably need to be savvy with TypeScript, something I am not.

Comment: Hey there Timothy G, thank you very much for helping with this. Your answer was very useful, thanks again.

Comment: @hustnzj You have to apply the `replace` from the last line in the `ts` file, then you can use the Markdown preview, Open the Dev Tools and copy the content of the Markdown Preview Webview `iframe`, save as HTML

Comment: Hi @rioV8, that's a great idea. Thanks for your reminder.